# Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9300) "no network" issue

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, rooting, custom-roms, 4.3-jelly-bean, unrooting

I bought my phone from a friend and I am the second user. It was rooted and was in modified status (when I checked About->device->status) but working fine and had zero issues. So yesterday I wanted to install a new ROM to get android 4.3 as what I had was android 4.1.2.

I installed [this](http://omegadroid.co/download-center/) Omega Rom (version is v58 - XXUGNB6).

Now everything is working fine except the calling feature, phone is fast as well but when I try to make a call it says

> "Not Registered on Network"

This was working fine before, and a friend has the same ROM installed and it works fine without any problems at all. Even calling is working fine.

What can I do to recover my phone? How can I unroot it? Does anyone know why I would be seeing this message?

**UPDATE**

I have found now that IMEI (under the battery) no of the device does not match with the IMEI I get when typing *#06#

The IMEI I get when dial *#06# starts with 004999 but the IMEI under the battery starts with 355994.

I flashed using ODIN again what I thought was the [stock ROM](http://samsung-updates.com/details/24621/Galaxy_S_3_International/GT-I9300/SKZ/I9300XXUGNA8.html). But it's not the original ROM which was in the mobile before, please find the below screenshot.

I read here as well : http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s3/general/ref-imei-efs-stuff-i9300-including-t2393289/

[image: About device]
[image: Error message]
[image: IMEI]
[image: Homescreen]

Comment: related/duplicate question: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81462/samsung-galaxy-s3-installed-omega-rom-not-detecting-the-sim

Comment: That IMEI is invalid. You need to check how to restore your original IMEI; I've read that case a couple of times with Samsung devices, if I remember correctly it had to do with some `/efs` partition specific to Samsung devices which sometimes gets corrupted when flashing custom ROMs. A Google search on [samsung efs imei](https://www.google.com/search?q=samsung+efs+imei) should get you started.

Comment: Tnx a lot, can you also share a link to do the flashing without using nodin tool. here the same issue is explained. http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/general/guide-recover-imei-9-steps-t1264021